# wireless network cannot see wired network until reboot

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, network-shares

We keep having an issue in a small office, most users on a wired network, but some connect to the wireless router.

The network setup is pretty small consists of:

1 16 port switch
1 8 port wifi router
1 modem

All users can always access the internet no problem. But sometimes (seemingly more and more often) the few users that are connected via wifi are not able to access items that are on the network, and wired users cannot access the wireless users shared folders etc.

After rebooting the devices everyone can see everyone.

What can I check that might be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Can be dying hardware. First thing I'd check is to pinpoint the device causing it. Reboot only one device and test if it works. If not, reboot the 2nd and test if it works. Its likely the router. If rebooting it points to the device, you can focus your attention to that device rather than rebooting all devices all the time.

If its not, on the next time things go bad, choose a different device as first device and repeat the circle until one device seems to need the reboot.

Lastly, I'd update the firmware of that device and see if it solves your problem. If not, maybe reset to factory defaults or in worst case, replace the device for a new one.

Answer (score 0):

The point of failure is most likely the WiFi router, but I wouldn't rule out the switch.

Sometimes a misbehaving device one network can flood the router's internal bridge between WiFi and wired networks, causing them to get partitioned off and act as two independent networks.  See if removing certain wired or WiFi devices helps.  I'd probably start with the wired ones... or just replace the equipment.

Also, the next time it happens, see if you can ping the router from both networks or if it's just one.  If it's just one, then it will probably be the wired side.

If the WiFi router is overheating, this can also contribute to failures.